# django Datefield is taken as UTC even though I have set it to 'Asia/Kolkata' in postgresql but in DateTimeField is taken time 'Asia/Kolkata' why

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

**My Models**

```
saleDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) #this field taken UTC
saleTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #this field taken 'Asia/Kolkata
```

**Settings.py**

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

using AWS Mumbai Region

Comment: Add the actual returned values for each field to your question. What is the data type for the fields in the Postgres table? `DateField` in Django is a datetime.date and that has no time zone: ` datetime.date.today()  datetime.date(2021, 1, 23)`.  A Postgres  `date` is the same: ` select '01/23/2021'::date; 2021-01-23`.

Comment: yes i read this in documentation can you please suggest me a solution i want same date in DateField –

Comment: You still have not shown what the values being returned are.  A date does not have a time zone so I can't see where you think it is at `UTC`?

Answer (score 0):

Django's DateField is not timezone-aware while DateTimeField is.  DateField is stored in Postgres database as date but DateTimeField as timestamptz.

Comment: yes i read this in documentation can you please suggest me a solution i want same date in DateField

Comment: I suggest you use DateTimeField instead of DateField.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the [Django DateField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

Keep in mind that it's generally considered good practice to store UTC times for the sake of consistency.

That said, you might give this a try:

```python
my_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))

# OR

my_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(default=timezone.now)
```

An example of converting timezones in code instead of the model:

```python
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# UTC time
utc_time = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print(f"UTC time: {utc_time}")
# Output: UTC time: 2022-09-20 17:04:04.766319+00:00

# Local time
lcl_time = datetime.now()
print(f"Local time: {lcl_time}")
# Output: Local time: 2022-09-20 10:04:04.766678

# Convert to America/Los_Angeles time zone
cvt_time = utc_time.astimezone(timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
print(f"Converted time: {cvt_time}")
# Output: Converted time: 2022-09-20 10:04:04.766319-07:00
```